How to modify array of objects after that is created inside a watcher
I have a Vue 3 app that is using composition API and TypeScript. For a breadcrumb into the code of a component there is a watcher that will push the route name and path inside an array of objects after a switch is checking for the correct route to use. At the moment I need to remove the first two objects from the created object array inside the watchers, I've tried using a splice, but seems not working inside the watchers. Is it possible to modify an array of objects to remove elements from it if a condition is true and directly from inside the watchers?

Please, provide code instead of just describing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "splice, but seems not working inside the watcher" - there's no such limitation, whatever happens is specific to your case


I've tried using a splice, but seems not working inside the watchers

It does work, but you have to use watch with deep: true.
But I suggest not to modify the current value, but to rewrite it entirely.
const breadcrumbs = ref([
  { label: 'Home', path: '/home' },
  { label: 'About', path: '/about' },
])

watch(someRef, () => {
  breadbrumbs.value = [
     ...breadcrumbs.value,
    { label: 'New crumb', path: '/crumb-path' },
  ]
})



